# How to fetch and assert and REST API in Python Unittests?

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary, python-unittest

while trying to fetch and assert a REST API, throwing a "TypeError". The following is the code which I am running

def test_get_action(self):
        action_id = self._get_action_id()
        """Get actions, Successful with response status 200"""
        resp = self.test_client.get_action(action_id)
        self.assertEqual(resp.response['status'], '200')
        self.assertEqual(resp.values()[0][0]['action_id'], action_id)

And I'm seeing the error as "TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing"

Further investigations:
* Running this test in Python 2.7 and seeing the above error
* I change the code differently as follow, but not able to derive this.

- self.assertListEqual(resp.values()[0][0]['action_id'], action_id)
- self. assertSequenceEqual(resp.values()[0][0]['action_id'], action_id)

I'm new to Python and unittests, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that `resp.values()` is returning a `dict_values` object  rather than a list.

Try wrapping the call to `resp.values()` in a call to `list()`:

```
self.assertEqual(list(resp.values())[0][0]['action_id'], action_id)
```